# jQuery noConflict() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8

So I'm developing on a platform that injects jQuery-1.2.6 every time when a page loads.  I developed my page to use jQuery-1.4.2, so when my page loads there are 2 jQuery instances on my page.

To avoid any conflict, I've included the following line in my JS file that is outside my page:

```
var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($)
```

Everything seems to be working if I use mc$ for where the $ was originally used.

I am getting an error in Firebug and IE that I don't know how to resolve.

Within a file that is injected on the platform when my page loads the developer has done:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

and the error in Firebug states: '$ is not a function'.

This error only started to show up once I made the change of:

```
var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

I'm thinking that by creating the mc$ variable that something broke with the developer's $(document)... call.  If so, I don't know how to resolve this and if not I would hope there is a solution that I can put into place to provide the functionality back to the developer's injected file.

Thanks!

Comment: `.noConflict()` is for compatibility with *other* JavaScript libraries/frameworks, multiple instances of jQuery (sans `.sub()` in 1.6+) in the same page is not supported in any way.

Comment: @Nick Craver the `noConflict()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) disagrees with you.  It specifically mentions passing `true` as an argument to deconflict the `jQuery` symbol as well.

Comment: @lawnsea - that's specifically (and limited at that) to 1.6+ (my mentioned exception above).  Note that you'll still have *many* problems even then, for example plugins are defined on the `jQuery` object, as are (likely) many event handlers, etc depending on jQuery or their plugins.  This comes from experience addressing these...remember if there weren't plugins, etc...there would be no reason to keep the old version in the first place.

Comment: @Nick - Please accept my apology. I did the due diligence I should have done earlier and took a look back in jQuery doc history and found that you're completely right. I'll donate the spurious upvotes to a good cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call order in your `<head>` section must be next:

1. jQuery library №1;
2. noConflict for it;
3. jQuery library №2.

`.noConflict()` can look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

And after use this syntax in the scripts:

```
mc$('#container').height();
```

Answer (score 4):

The root cause is loading two instances of jQuery into one page. By the sounds of it, the original instance (1.2.6) of jQuery is also being unbound from the global $ variable.

From looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/, you could try supplying an additional parameter to the jQuery.noConflict() call to denote unloading jQuery as well, as it seems your instance of 1.4.2 is being loaded before 1.2.6.

Beyond that, without testing that exact scenario I don't know what other help to offer :)

Comment: Interesting.  There's apparently something I'm not doing right because by setting `jQuery.noConflict(true);` a number of my plugins break.  Thanks everyone for their input so far.

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately, this is to be expected. Most (if not all) jQuery plugins depend on the "jQuery" keyword to initialize, so using `var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict(true)` would cause them to break. Using your above scenario, you will probably have to go through your plugins and replace the `})(jQuery);` variable on the last line with `})(mc$);`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this answer helpful: [jquery noConflict not working in IE8 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830510/jquery-noconflict-not-working-in-ie8-only)