# Use Multiple jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie and I am designing a website. I dont know about jQuery.
My problem is:

1. I am using a script that uses jQuery.1.7.min.js for a sliding banner images with description.
2. Also, i am using another script to show latest events on the same page which uses jQuery.1.8.3.js

What happens is:

1. when i put both jQuery files no script works.
2. if i use 1.7, only (1) works
3. if i use 1.8.3 the banner disappears and only (2) works.

what can i do?

Code:

```
<div class="flexslider-quote">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div class="date"><strong>29</strong><span> May, 2012</span>
            </div>
            <p><a href="#" class="link">test 1</p> </li> <li> <div class="date"><strong>21</strong><span> May, 2012</span></div> <p><a href="#" class="link">test 2</p> </li> </ul> </div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Second:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slider')._TMS({
            settings
        })
    });
</script>
<div id="slide">
    <div class="slider">
        <cms:show_repeatable 'banner_repeatable_images'>
            <ul class="items">
                <li>bannerimage
                    <div class="banner">
                        <p class="text-1">banner title</p>
                        <p class="text-2">banner text</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just inlcude this link to your page `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: Probably the old script use deprecated function/api's try use the latest version of the scripts. If you can provide a demo on jsfiddle, provide your code and reference the scripts you are using

Comment: @laaposto I don't see how it's going to solve his problem.

Comment: Use Jquery `noConflict()`

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward how can i place the code here? coz its too big to fir in

Comment: @SurjithSM noConflict aint working it out. Is there a way to put it, coz what i read here and tried to use, that didnt work. And i am no good with jQuery.

Comment: @laaposto I need to use both the scripts and cant use the latest one only.

Comment: Try reducing you code to a simple demo illustrating the issue; it will be simple to debug and help you

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Sir, can you please check the code and help me with the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided not much elements to investigate, but with some google searches I think that your plugins are:

1. TM_slider --> http://mydummysite.com.au/qnpx/documentation/JustSlider/
2. flexSlider --> http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

I have combined them both in the fiddle with jQuery 1.9.2 and it's "working fine". Probably your problem is somewhere else.

Eventually you can give a try to jQuery migrate:

> This plugin can be used to detect and restore APIs or features that
>   have been deprecated in jQuery and removed as of version 1.9. See the
>   warnings page for more information regarding messages the plugin
>   generates. For more information about the changes made in jQuery 1.9,
>   see the upgrade guide and blog post.

Ref: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.slider')._TMS({
        show: 0,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        prevBu: '.prev',
        nextBu: '.next',
        playBu: '.play',
        pagNums: false,
        slideshow: 7000
    })

    jQuery('.flexslider-quote').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        slideshow: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        smoothHeight: true,
        prevText: "",
        nextText: ""
    })

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/J6Bq2/

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a few versions of jQuery, you need to use jQuery.noConflict().

Please, read the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/.

Also read my answer to the similar question here: [jQuery noConflict() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239896/jquery-noconflict-problem/7426983#7426983)

Hope, that will help.